# Current.SessionID convert to Guid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, guid, sessionid

I have requirement to create Guid based on SessionID from CurrentContext. That Guid is stored in some TraceContext class that is later logged to DB.

Now I'm using Guid.NewGuid() for creating new guid, but I would like to create guid based on sessionId.

I've tried parsing it:

```
var sessionId = HttpContext.Session.SessionId;
var result = Guid.Parse(sessionId);
```

Problem is that SessionId is 24 char string, for example:
   **`jeycop2ty20icvuvh2jks20g`**
and Guid must be 32 char long, so I get Parse exception.

Is there any way to create Guid from this string?

Comment: _"I have requirement to create Guid based on SessionID from CurrentContext"_ - why? What is the reasoning behind this? Does it have to be _based on_, or _related to_?

Comment: You will also get a parse exception because that session ID contains characters that are illegal in a guid - which is usually written as a 32 char (plus some dashes) hexadecimal representation of the 128 bit number that it really is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Both solutions are hackish and you should consider not using a Guid at all or adding one to your session (see André's solution).**

**Solution 1**

You can override `SessionIdManager` to provide a Guid as SessionId

See [SessionIDManager.CreateSessionID Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager.createsessionid(v=vs.140).aspx) and [Session Identifiers documentation (Custom Session Identifiers)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178582(v=vs.140).aspx).

**Code from MDSN Library :**

Custom SessionIDManager class

```
  public class GuidSessionIDManager : SessionIDManager
  {

    public override string CreateSessionID(HttpContext context)
    {
      return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }


    public override bool Validate(string id)
    {
      try
      {
        Guid testGuid = new Guid(id);

        if (id == testGuid.ToString())
          return true;
      }
      catch
      {
      }

      return false;
    }
  }
```

Inject it in web.config :

```
<sessionState
  ...
  sessionIDManagerType="Your.Namespace.GuidSessionIDManager, YourAssemblyName"
/>
```

---

**Solution 2**

The [default implementation of SessionIdManager](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Web/a.html#e4f076f835fc709c) builds a 15bytes array to generate a string. A Guid is 16bytes so you could Decode the string to a 15 bytes array then building a Guid from it with 0 as last byte. The implementation might change in a future version.

Comment: Thanks on such detailed answer, I will take this as correct answer. I understand you all, but I can't change sessionID generation. What about creating MD5 hash from sessionId, and than converting it to Guid. I've write that code and it's working, but I don't know is there going to be some consequences later?

Comment: @freshbm You introduce a risk of colliding Guids : the MD5 hash of different session ids might have the same value and you'll have one Guid representing different sessions !

Comment: This is spectacular, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

A `GUID` is a [[G]lobally [U]nique [ID]entifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier), it's not a hashing algorithm.

If you want a Session ID to be mapped to a GUID, you will have to make a mapping table, or similar.

**Alternatively** you might consider, storing a GUID in the Session when it is first created.

```
// Global.asax
public void Session_OnStart()
{
  Session["GUIDSessionID"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

and subsequently reading it every page load.

```
var sessionId = HttpContext.Current.Session["GUIDSessionID"];
var result = Guid.Parse(sessionId);
```

This could ofcourse be done without, converting it back and forth from a string.